# Trouble with installing new ADT Plugin

Tags: eclipse, sdk, eclipse-plugin, adt

I deside to update my SDK in Eclipse. I go to SDK Manager and update Android SDK Tool to the latest version. Then I open Eclipse and it shows me a warning message:

This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.2 or above.
Current version is 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685.
Please update ADT to the latest version.

I deside to update my ADT plugin (Help > Install New Software > ADT Plugin - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) and I get above error:

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Tracer for OpenGL ES 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)
  Software currently installed: Tracer for OpenGL ES 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.group 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Tracer for OpenGL ES 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger 23.0.3.1327240)
    Tracer for OpenGL ES 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Tracer for OpenGL ES 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)
    To: com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger [23.0.3.1327240]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:

Could you help me please? I´m very depressed because I couldn´t do now nothing in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue, and here's what I did.

1. Got to "Help > Install New Software"
2. Click on "What is already installed?"
3. Remove any existing components that you wish to replace/update.
4. Once done, either install the new updated via the ADT url or download the zip and install from that (details [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)).

Everything works fine thereafter. Oh, I had some issues with the OpenGL Tracer, and since I didn't see a need for that at the moment, I unchecked that during installation.

Comment: Thanks, but what you mean: Remove any existing components that you wish to replace/update. What can I uninstall? Here is list of my components:

Android DDMS, Android Development Tools, Android Hierarchy Viewer, Android Traceview, Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Keytool
Tracer for OpenGL ES

Comment: In my case, only the components originally installed with the ADT (that is the Android* components that you state above). Ignore the rest.

Comment: this method works. just uninstall the ADP plugins from version 22 and then install 23.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error I couldn't solve... What I did was to download a new [ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and then configured the SDK link to the previous (updated) one.

Answer (score 0):

Solution extracted from this forum http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/487240/:

Run eclipse 
Rename eclipse exe to eclipse.exe.back
Run updates
Updates executed successfully
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22V or above. Current version is 21V. Please update ADT to the latest version. While Updating....., 
If you getting error while remove or uninstall 21V, the solution is, first do rename the eclipse into eclipse.exe.back and update 23

Answer (score 0):

After following different methods i failed ..
But i did the following and it worked like a charm for me :)

1) Open Eclipse

2)rename eclipse.exe to something like eclipse.exe.old[IM not sure if this step is required]

3)Goto **Help->Install New software -> What is *Already Installed* link**

4)In "**Already Installed software**",
select first item and uninstall and DO NOT RESTART ECLIPSE when it asks you to.

5)Then select the newer version of this package from **Help->Install New software**

6)The plugin will get installed without any issues. It will ask for Eclipse restart.Ignore.
Follow steps 3-6 for other packages as well.Hope this helps